# Create alias with variable input?

Tags: command-line, alias

So I've seen a similar question to this, but using fish. I though am using vanilla ubuntu 20 terminal.

What I have is an alias for a directory `1dir='cd such/and/such/and/such'`, and another for running a python script, where it needs an input of a file which is variable.

```
pyGraph='python3 -m bruhPy [filename.py]'
```

1. Thing is - I obviously don't just always run the same filename.py. How do I make sure I can write `pyGraph filename.py`? Will that work?
2. Can the 2 aliases be combined in one command? Such as `1dir pyGraph filename.py`? Or do they have to be executed separately?

Comment: Ubuntu 20?   So you're using a Ubuntu Core 20 server system?   (the *year* products don't forget are different products to the more widely used *year.month* systems; ie. 20 & 20.04 are different Ubuntu products).

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll write `alias pyGraph='python3 -m bruhPy`. Then `pyGraph file.py` is expanded to `python3 -m bruhBy file.py`
2. Aliases are only expanded for the **first** word of a command. You'll need to write `1dir` and `pyGraph ...` as 2 separate command (with a semicolon or newline separating them)

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do is write a function:

```
function pyg {
  cd such/and/such/and/such
  python3 -m bruhPy "$1"
}
```

and call it using `pyg <filename>`.

I find that I resort to functions whenever my aliases need more power.

Comment: Looks grand. I've got another answer with a function, but it's quite longer, and I don't really see why, when yours seems so straight forward, and sufficient. What do you think about it?
.
`go_and_run() {
  [[ -z "$1" ]] && { echo "No argument provided."; return 1; }
  cd such/and/such/and/such;
  python3 -m bruhPy "$1";
}`

Comment: That function uses more errorchecking (which is good): "did the user supply a file".  
I considered adding a `if [[ -f "$1" ]] ...` which checks for a file at that location, which will also make it longer. You can also check whether the file is readable and such. If you like I can update the function with more error checking and comments.